# How to get random values from different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to draw data from various arrays and wonder how best to do it.

Now I have:

```
$array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
$array2 = ['Q', 'W', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'Y'];
$array3 = ['Z', 'X', 'V', 'N'];

$maxResults = 11;
$numberOfArrays = 3;
$inGroup = ceil($maxResults / $numberOfArrays); // 4
```

The most important condition here is that an equal number of data should be taken from each table, except for the last.

I would like receive for example:

```
$results = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Q', 'W', 'P', 'R', 'Z', 'X', 'V'];
```

Comment: What??? What are you expecting here?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Please give us an example input AND expected output

Comment: how much should be taken from the last array?

Comment: I've also answered this question based on the understand that I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know how much you need to take from the last array but I used two ( mean 3 element will be selected from last array). For what I understand from your question here is the answer to your question.

```
    <?php
    $array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
    $array2 = ['Q', 'W', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'Y'];
    $array3 = ['Z', 'X', 'V', 'N'];

    $maxResults = 11;
    $numberOfArrays = 3;
    $inGroup = ceil($maxResults / $numberOfArrays); // 4

    $arrays = array($array1, $array2, $array3);


    function draw_data($arrays, $inGroup, $maxResults){
        $str = array();
        $arraysLength = count($arrays);
        for($i=0; $i< $arraysLength; $i++){

            if($i == $arraysLength){ /*If it is the last array */
                /*
                * This part is actually not clear in the question so I'm guessing you need to take 2 element of the last array so 
                */

                if(count($arrays[$i]) >= 2){
                    for($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++){
                        $rand = rand(0, 2); /* because array is 0 based index */
                        if(count($str)<$maxResults){
                            $str[] = $arrays[$i][$rand];
                        }
                    }
                }

            }else{ /*If not the last array */

                /* so that we don't get an index out of bound exception 
                * e.g $array2 = ['Q', 'W', 'P'] and $inGroup is 4 we can't get 4 elements from $array2 
                */

                if(count($arrays[$i]) >= $inGroup){
                    for($j = 0; $j < $inGroup; $j++){
                        $rand = rand(0, $inGroup-1); /* because array is 0 based index */
                        if(count($str)<$maxResults){
                            $str[] = $arrays[$i][$rand];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return $str;
    }

    print_r(json_encode(draw_data($arrays, $inGroup,$maxResults)));
?>
```

**RESULTS**

["A","C","A","D","W","Q","W","R","Z","Z","N"]

Answer (score 0):

```
    shuffle($array1);
    shuffle($array2);
    shuffle($array3);
    $a1 = array_slice($array1,0, rand(0,count($array1)));
    $a2 = array_slice($array2,0, rand(0,count($array2)));
    $a3 = array_slice($array3,0, rand(0,count($array3)));
    $rand = array_merge($a1,$a2,$a3);
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JohnConde  there only built-in functions, what should i explain?

Comment: *how* this solves their problem and *what* that code is doing. Just because the functions are built in doesn't mean the solution is obvious.